# How to clean uninstall jupyter

Tags: python, terminal, pip

I can't cleanyl uninstall jupyter with command

```
$ pip uninstall jupyter
```

[image]

Comment: How did you install it? Can you add the output from `ls -l $(which jupyter)` please?

Comment: I installed it with pip tool, maybe "sudo pip install jupyter"

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 222 11月 16 00:19 /usr/local/bin/jupyter

Comment: Are you sure you have the right Python version?

Comment: You mean what? The command "python -V" shows I have the version python 2.7.12